# Jest Run All Tests(include only/skip) in CI

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

While in development we occasionally use `skip` or `only` to debug a particular test or test suit. Accidentally, we might forget to revert the cases and push the code for PR. I am looking for a way to detect or automatically run all tests even for `skip` and `only` tests in our CI pipeline(using Github action). It can be in either case as follow.

1. Fail the test when there are `skip` or `only` tests.
2. Run all tests even for `skip` and `only`.

Very much appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't know about running, but there is an ESLINT rule that disallows disabled tests: https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/no-disabled-tests.md

Comment: I think that there isn't a clean way to do what you wish for. `skip` and `only` are not meant to be somehow ignored so tests could run. I guess you could write some script that would check each test file before running tests and remove all `skip` and `only` keywords (also with `xtest`, `xit` etc.), but it sounds nasty. Maybe you could use some ESLint rules that disallows disabled tests as NoNameProvided said and add stage before running test to CI which would fail a build if ESLint rules are failing.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a solution for the second part of the question about running all tests even for `skip` and `only`. I don't think it's elegant solution, but it works and it's easy to implement.

First of all you need to change test runner to [jest-circus](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/main/packages/jest-circus) if you work with jest bellow 27.x version. We need it so our custom test environment will use `handleTestEvent` function to watch for `setup` events. To do so, install `jest-circus` with `npm i jest-circus` and then in your `jest.config.js` set [testRunner](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testrunner-string) property:

```js
//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    testRunner: 'jest-circus/runner',
    ...
}
```

From Jest 27.0 they changed default test runner to `jest-circus` so you can skip this step if you have this or higher version.

Then you have to write custom test environment. I suggest to write it based on `jsdom` so for example we also have access to `window` object in tests and etc. To do so run in terminal `npm i jest-environment-jsdom` and then create custom environment like so:

```js
//custom-jsdom-environment.js

const JsDomEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom')

class CustomJsDomEnvironment extends JsDomEnvironment {

    async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
        if(process.env.IS_CI === 'true' && event.name === 'setup') {
            this.global.describe.only = this.global.describe
            this.global.describe.skip = this.global.describe
            this.global.fdescribe = this.global.describe
            this.global.xdescribe = this.global.describe

            this.global.it.only = this.global.it
            this.global.it.skip = this.global.it
            this.global.fit = this.global.it
            this.global.xit = this.global.it

            this.global.test.only = this.global.test
            this.global.test.skip = this.global.test
            this.global.ftest = this.global.test
            this.global.xtest = this.global.test
        }
    }
}

module.exports = CustomJsDomEnvironment
```

And inform `jest` to properly use it:

```js
//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    testRunner: 'jest-circus/runner',
    testEnvironment: 'path/to/custom/jsdom/environment.js',
    ...
}
```

Then you just have to setup custom environment value `IS_CI` in your CI pipeline and from now on all your skipped tests will run.

Also in custom test environment you could watch for skipped test and throw an error when your runner find skip/only. Unfortunately throwing an error in this place won't fail a test. You would need to find a way to fail a test outside of a test.

```js
//custom-jsdom-environment.js

const JsDomEnvironment = require('jest-environment-jsdom')
const path = require('path')

class CustomJsDomEnvironment extends JsDomEnvironment {

    constructor(config, context) {
        super(config, context)
        const testPath = context.testPath
        this.testFile = path.basename(testPath)
    }

    async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
        if(process.env.IS_CI === 'true' && event.name === 'add_test') {
            if(event.mode === 'skip' || event.mode === 'only') {
                const msg = `Run ${event.mode} test: '${event.testName}' in ${this.testFile}`
                throw new Error(msg)
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = CustomJsDomEnvironment
```

Comment: Very nice answer with good explanation, code examples and links 